# how can i join 4 tables and get the last value from a column in one of the tables

Tags: mysql

how can i join 4 tables and get the last value from a column in one of the tables plus if the any table has no related records it should also be shown but with null value. the tables are :
product,orders,order_history and schedule .
i want to get all of the orders information and get each order shipping date "schedule" as well. please note that each order could have only one shipping date "schedule" and the value can be null , the orders history table could have more than one record for each order and could be null as well . the relations between tables are as follows :
company > product > orders > order_history > schedule

the foreign keys are as following :
- product table > company_id for company table
- orders table > product_id for product table
- order_history > order_id for orders table
- schedule > order_history_id for order_history table

the code i have which seems wrong :

```
    SELECT product.name as product_name,orders.id as order_id,orders.quantity as order_quantity,orders.price as order_price,order_history.status as status,orders.created_at as order_date 
        FROM product 
        INNER JOIN orders ON product.id = orders.product_id AND product.company_id = 1
        LEFT JOIN order_history ON order_history.order_id = orders.id
        GROUP BY orders.id
```

i really would appreciate your help . however , if you can provide a solution that dose not require changing the schema then that would very very be great and helpful . if you had to adjust the schema then please provide the solution along with any suggestions to deal with the current schema as i am working on a prototype for an e-commerce api and i have to deliver in 24 hours!!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: do you mean provide the database schema (sql) ?

Comment: Please read [**My Post**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) On how to properly ask a question.. we need more info.. theres also tips and tricks on formatting to help you out as well :)